# "This company makes quality product" - how to explain correctly why there is no "a" before "product"?

Tags: indefinite-article

The question is in the title - I know that "product" here serves as a plural, but it's hard to google how this situation is called in linguistics, and if there are any formal rules that could be learned to better understand and generalize this occurrence.

I heard it in a lesson recording and I couldn't formulate why it sounded so organic despite appearing to be incorrect - it was a reading of an article from some unspecified journal. Sorry for not providing the source, it's just rather awkward, as you can imagine.

Comment: Please supply a real-life  example, with its link IN the question, which is either  taken from the net or a publication.

Comment: If there's only a single product being mass-produced, then maybe the singular could be used without the indefinite article (a/an)... but I would expect to see it as a title in a magazine article or in a newspaper. Articles are often omitted in headlines for reasons of space and for punchier titles.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you that's exactly right! I heard it in a lesson recording and I couldn't formulate why it sounded so organic despite appearing to be incorrect - it was a reading of an article from some unspecified journal, and they do indeed do that. Sorry for not providing the source, it's just rather awkward, you can imagine.

Comment: [Definition of "product"](https://www.lexico.com/definition/product) - **mass noun** Commercially manufactured articles, especially recordings, viewed collectively. *‘They succeeded by manufacturing commercially viable product that people found beneficial to their lives.’*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's marketing-speak (or perhaps production-engineering-speak) to use *product* as a mass noun.

See for example sense 1 [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/product). It's not marked as jargon, but I don't think many people would use it that way in ordinary conversation.